# What is preferred way to pass data dictionaries using relay

Tags: relayjs, relay

what is preferred way to pass data dictionaries using relay,
for example I have in interface

```
UsersList = [
   {
     userName 
     // each user has select control
     CountrySelectControl {
         value = Country
         options = [All Countries List]
    }
]
```

What is the right way to read All Countries List?
As I understand it's not a good idea to query graphQl like this

```
{ users { userName, country, countriesList } }
```

So the only way I see I need to query countriesList at root, and pass it via props manually to every children component?

```
class Blabla extends Relay.Route {
  static queries = {
    users: (Component) => Relay.QL`
      query UsersQuery {
        users { ${Component.getFragment('user')} },
      }
    `,
    countriesList: (Component) => Relay.QL`
      query countriesListQuery {
        countriesList { ${Component.getFragment('countriesList')} },
      }
    `,
...
}
```

And if i have a lot of dictionaries and some more deep UI structure this becomes a pain.

Or I can somehow to pass root data deeper in the tree without explicitly write this data in props. (I mean without context)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can pass root data deeper in tree without explicitly writing `countryList` as props.

Suppose, we have data of a continent and the countries that belongs to it. We have nested UI components. For example, `ContinentComponent` includes a `CountryListComponent`, which needs a list of countries. A `CountryListComponent` consists of a number of `CountryComponent`, which needs a list of states. Instead of having `ContinentComponent` pass country list and state list all the way down to `CountryListComponent` and `CountryComponent`, we can utilize high-level prop.

We can specify the high-level prop `continent` in the high-level component `ContinentComponent` as follows:

```
export default Relay.createContainer(ContinentComponent, {
  fragments: {
    continent: () => Relay.QL`
      fragment on Continent {
        ${CountryListComponent.getFragment('continent')},
      }
    `,
  },
});
```

Instead of `country list` prop, only the prop `continent` is passed to CountryListComponent from the ContinentComponent.

Next, we specify the necessary props in the `CountryListComponent`:

```
export default Relay.createContainer(CountryListComponent, {
  fragments: {
    continent: () => Relay.QL`
      fragment on Continent {
        countryList(first: 100) {
          edges {
            node {
              id,
              name,
            },
            ${CountryComponent.getFragment('country')},
          },
        },
      }
    `,
  },
});
```

Now, `CountryListComponent` passes a specific prop value `this.props.continent.countryList.edges[index].node` to CountryComponent.

This use case is one of the primary motivations of Relay.js.

Comment: You still need to pass this continent root prop all the way down to React component where you need it. The main idea that I want to explicitly show that user uses CountryList, but if this list is used inside UserList I need to pass a lot of duplicates for each user on create.

Comment: @ivanstarkov, about root prop, that's not correct. For example, `CountryComponent` needs to be passed only `country` prop, if it does not need anything else under root prop. About `countryList` prop, it is no longer explicitly passed to every level in the tree. Anyway, for your problem, does the country list vary for different users?